# VBA - Select Top of Matrix

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a "worksheet_selectionChange" event to fire a macro whenever a cells within certain ranges are selected.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Target.Cells.Offset(-???,0).Value
        Case "LABEL_1"
            Tenor = "2W"
            Call MyLameMacro()
        Case....
    End Select
End Sub
```

Those ranges look like little matricies:

[image]

If the user selects any of the cells underneath label, I want VBA to lookup whatever the label is at the top. Using offset would work if I knew exactly how many rows up to Label, but its not constant....

Is there another way to go about that?

Thanks - KC

Comment: 1) Make your label as named range. 2) When cell is selected, compare selected cell's column with named range's column.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a named range, because I have about 10 of these matricies (so want to make it kind of generic)

Comment: Then if all labels are in the same row, then, to get label, you could take column of selected cell and known row.

Comment: Use tables, that will give more options and control over these things. Tables of have thing like 'Headers'. :)

Comment: My matricies will be aligned in a 2x2, 3x3 fashion (so ie, 2x2 = 4 different labels, and in different rows and columns).  My first though was to try and use a 'Ctrl-Shift-Up' style select, where excel selects the first row of data automatically, but I'm not sure how to do it without changing the activecell

Comment: We *do not* see your data layout, so some help is advised.

Comment: @keynesiancross i agree with JohnyL, we need to see more of your data to understand how to select the labels

Comment: If you know the name of the label you could search for it in the column and gets its row position.  Then access it in (row, column) format.  Or you could prompt to select the label and use the target cell.  There are a few ways.  I agree the least complex of which is to put the labels in the same row,col (like a table) making it easy to reference that range.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code The *name of the label* is not an option for OP as he answered me earlier :)

Comment: pretty hard to do a case select if you don't know the potential label strings . . isn't it?

Comment: so to use Ctrl-Shift-Up without changing the activecell: `Target.End(xlUp).Value` but this only works if there are no blanks between the chosen cell and the label row and the label row is in row 1 or the row above the label row is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring further information about the layout ... you can use formatting to build your own search algorithm.  This will slow down if it has to go through thousands of lines (find another way if your data set is that large).

You'll have to replace "labelColor" and "notLabel" with the background color of the label rows.  This is assuming the above picture is accurate, and "Label" is highlighted.  To find the value to replace them with, simply select the cell in question, then type "debug.print selection.interior.color" into the immediate window in VBA.

By placing the label value and the origin address in parentheses after your lame macro, you can preserve those values in the macro.

I did not test this.  In order to do so I would have to guess at the setup of your workbook ... but an approximation of this code should work for you.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
searchLoop:
    If i > 100 Then
        MsgBox ("Infinite loop.  Click OK to stop")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Target.Offset([-i], 0).Interior.Color = labelColor Then Call MyLameMacro(Target.Offset([-i], 0), Target.address)
    If Target.Offset([-i], 0).Interior.Color = notLabel Then
        If Target.Offset([-i], 0).Value = "Value" Then Call MyLameMacro(Target.Offset([-i], [-1]).Value, Target.address)
        i = i + 1
        GoTo searchLoop
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  I actually combined this approach (with color) and then used Target.End(xlUp).Value.  When I reached the color I after, I could run my macro.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!